# Can not override border-box :before and :after with border-radius

Tags: css, border-box

So I got this theme http://demo.theme.co/ethos-1/
and wanted to make the top squares round.

The only way I can get them like that is if I change

```
*,*:before,*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
to
*,*:before,*:after {
    border-radius:100px;
}
```

The problem is it makes every box like shape on the site round. Where as I only want the top post previews to be round.

any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning- why do you feel that removing `box-sizing` in favor of `border-radius` on a wildcard selector is the only solution?  Why not target the specific class for those boxes?

Comment: are you trying to achieve something like this? http://i.imgur.com/4SpqQSh.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `.entry-cover{border-radius: 100px;}` to your CSS. This class is added for the elements on top.

Answer (score 0):

```
.entry-cover {
   border-radius:100px;
}
```

Use class for topmost posts